# Why is Polymer adding stuff to the (non-shadow) dom?

Tags: css, polymer, google-chrome-devtools, shadow-dom

I'm using polymer 1.0 and I have a html-file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Polyfill Web Components support for older browsers -->
    <script src="../vendors/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <!-- 2. Use HTML Imports to bring in the elements. -->
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../vendors/paper-item/paper-item-body.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-drawer-panel>
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div>Application</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-item scope="paper-icon-item">
        <paper-icon-button icon="favorite"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-item-body two-line>
          <div>Alphonso Engelking</div>
          <div secondary>Change photo</div>       
        </paper-item-body> 
      </paper-icon-item>  
    </paper-header-panel>
    <paper-header-panel main>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div>Title</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div>   Main content.. </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect it with the Chrome dev tools I see the following dom:
[image: Messy dom]

How come polymer is adding divs to the light dom? Why are things not hidden in the shadow dom? More specifically, the selected div element is screwing up the styling, how do I prevent it from messing up the layout?

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html#shadow-dom-is-awesome-why-is-there-a-shady-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 1.0, Polymer uses [shadyDOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html) as default for all browsers(even where shadow DOM is supported).
What this means is that even on chrome, content inside local dom(Polymer name of shadow/shady dom) will be spilled on to *light* dom and will be accessible using dom manipulation APIs.

You can opt to use shadow dom where it is supported by tweaking global polymer [settings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html).

```
<script>
    window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
    window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
</script>
```